# External CSS not being implemented

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep a fixed header in place on a web page and for the main content, when scrolled, does not move over the main header.

I am failing to understand why inline CSS works as expected but when switching the same CSS properties to an external style sheet, it fails to work.  The external style sheet is being found as the first `<div>` has its properties set correctly.  I have tried using both id and class on the second div but neither seem to work.  This is the code using ids rather than classes.

**index.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body style="height:100%; width:100%">
        <div id="fixed-header">
            <h1>Page Heading</h1>
        </div> 
        <div id="main-content">
            <!-- a number of articles and sections -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css/style.css:**

```css
#fixed-header {
    position:fixed;
    height:100px;
    top:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#main-content {
    position:absolute; 
    top:100px; 
    left:0px; 
    right:0px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

There is no other CSS code.

If I change `<div id="main-content">` to `<div style="position:absolute; top:100px; bottom:100px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:auto;">` it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I realize that there is a bottom:100px in the inline CSS and that there isn't in the external style sheet.

Comment: If I add the bottom:100px to the external style sheet, it works.  Need to understand why but at least it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This boils down to a basic understanding of CSS.

If you only specify the top of an absolutely positioned element, the rest of that element will size normally (its height will be the height of the content inside the element). When an absolutely positioned element is tall enough to go off the bottom of the screen, that creates a scroll bar in the body/html.

Putting the `bottom` property on your content limits the height of your content so the content container element itself can scroll individually of the body.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: There's no difference between inline CSS and having it in an external stylesheet. That's a red herring. I don't see any example in the question that shows evidence of this behavior. By the way his "inline" example has the `bottom` property defined... that's probably why, he was missing a property in the external stylesheet.

Comment: Read the comments below the question. The asker has realized that they made a mistake with the inline CSS and external CSS not being the same, and now they're asking how the `bottom` CSS property works.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  It just seemed a bit strange to me that even by specifying a bottom:0px in the external CSS it worked, yet by omitting it, the main content just scrolled over the fixed heading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a big point here. This is the way a browser gives preference to the styles attached to a web page:

INLINE > ON-PAGE > EXTERNAL

So, you have to remove the inline css when you apply the external one.

And if you want to say get 100px as the result then in the external css file put height and width as 100px after height and width as 100%.

Answer (score 0):

why??
it is because you fix the div with the 100px in the botton and you close the box if you want you gave to the div the width 0px left and 0px right nowyou can say to width 100% so you gaved him(the div) an width nov for the height you say stay 100px from the top of the view height and then you say stay 100px from the bottom so you "closed" the box and now your overflow can work correctly i hope that explained a little bit the why because of what

Answer (score -1):

You must put the height to html tag too!

Look this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4p73j4r6/)

```
html, body {height:100%}
```